# How to hide a div when another toggles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, hide

I have an image inside a div that on click toggles another div and I want to hide the div that contains the image when the new div appears. When I use only the abreInfo() it works, but I also want to hide the container div. How can I do it?

```
function abreInfo(event, id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#" + id).toggle("slow");
}

function fechardiv(div) {
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";
}
```

http://codepen.io/Ryuh/pen/BzaNLL

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487780/how-to-hide-a-div-when-another-toggles/37488153#37488153)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just with jQuery more easier like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#id').show();
});
```

Full code here https://jsfiddle.net/yLhq7ga6/

Answer (score 0):

Inside abreInfo() add `$(event.currentTarget).closest('div').hide()`.

`.closest()` gets the first ancestor that matches the selector. I'd make sure the container has a class, to make sure you hit the right element.

```
function abreInfo(event, id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#"+id).toggle("slow");
    $(event.currentTarget).closest('div').hide("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `abreInfo()` function. If you just want to display next div after hiding image. Just use your function like this. Also remove `abreInfo()` function from `onclick`  [like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEWbqq)

```
function fechardiv(div){          
  $("#"+div).hide();
  $("#"+div).next().fadeIn();
}
```